# Execute a JAR from WCF Service

Tags: java, c#, xml, wcf, process

I have a WCF service running in my server and it has to save some information in an Oracle database, creates a XML file and after that it has to call a JAR that signs the XML and sends the signed XML file to an external Web Service.

The JAR is executed and it signs the file well but when it tries to send the XML to the external Web Service it got this error:

```
Fallo al acceder al WSDL en: https://theExternalWebServiceUri?wsdl. 
Ha fallado con: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: 
the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty.
```

I have to say that when I execute the JAR in the cmd, it does everything well, it signs the file and sends the file to the external Web Service perfectly.

I'm using this code to call the JAR from my WCF service:

```
Process signProcessWithJava = new Process();
signProcessWithJava.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
signProcessWithJava.StartInfo.FileName = "java";
signProcessWithJava.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-jar " + jarPath + " " + arg1 + " " + arg2;
signProcessWithJava.Start();
signProcessWithJava.WaitForExit();
```

I tried setting the admin user in the Process too, but the JAR didn't execute.

I set the admin user with this lines before Start method:

```
signProcessWithJava.StartInfo.Domain = "domain";
signProcessWithJava.StartInfo.UserName = "Admin";
System.Security.SecureString ss = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (var item in "password".ToCharArray())
{
    ss.AppendChar(item);
}
signProcessWithJava.StartInfo.Password = ss;
```

I hope you can help me.

And any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it.

The problem was that I had these lines in my ProxyConfig file:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "resources/cert");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

And I was setting the path with "resources/cert" and I replaced it with the absolute path:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\runid\\resources\\cert");
//System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "resources/cert");
```

It's weird because It always worked in the comand line before but not from the WCF service call.